# A way for fetcher.load to not participate in revalidation

Tags: remix.run

With the release of Remix.run v1.10, there's a note in the changelog:

> fetcher.load calls now participate in revalidation - they always should have to avoid stale data on your page!

Is there a way to disable that?
I only want my fetcher to load once, when I manually trigger it.

Comment: Looks like there was originally going to be an option to opt-out but not sure it was implemented https://github.com/remix-run/remix/discussions/2775#discussioncomment-4660420. Might be worth asking in Discord https://discord.com/channels/770287896669978684/770287896669978687